# Vim became very slow when process long string

Tags: vim, vi

I have a file contains some very long string(about 3000 characters), When I open it with Vim, and navigate with h,l,j,k. Vim became very very slow, each time I type a key, I need to wait for seconds. But when I open it with Vi, it seems very fast, So I was wondering is there any options I can set to Let vim process long string fast?

I am using Vim 7.3 on SunOS. my work involves lot's of long text lines everyday.

Comment: try turning off syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is defined via regular expressions, and the matching can consume a lot of resources, especially on long lines and large buffers. You can turn off syntax for the problematic buffer with `:setlocal syntax=`, or disable it completely with `:syntax off`.

Recent Vim versions (7.4 with a "huge" build) also have a `:syntime` command that can show you *which* syntax rule is problematic, so that you may be able to disable only parts of the syntax highlighting.

Other settings can make working with large files slow. The [LargeFile - Edit large files quickly](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin detects and disables those automatically for you.